# consuming web api, ports on different machine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

my simple web app has web api and web mvc project. from mvc app I'm consuming web api service using ajax.

Right now my uri looks like this

```
var uri = 'http://localhost:2266/api/cars';
```

and on web api side I need to enable cors for communication with my mvc app.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:2256", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

this setup working just fine on my machine, since I want to share this with my friend how can I make this ports values `2256` and `2266` to be same on each machine?\

Or if it's not what do you suggest to make this values configurable?

> Thank you, but obviously I was not clear enough: I'm asking how can I know on
>   different computer which port should be used, and upon that to include
>   that port instead of this 2256, 2266?

Comment: Give multiple values by comma separating the origins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port number is just the tooling (VS) making it easy for you to debug locally (`localhost`) - it "separates" each of your web sites by assigning a *random* port number all living in your local machine under 'localhost` (aka "domain").

You can in fact assign one yourself (or change whatever VS assigns) with the caveat of making sure it doesn't conflict with any other service/existing port in use in your local machine (more below).

> "share this with my friend"

Unsure what that means. As above `localhost` is `local`, so assuming on the (live/production) net - then *you* assign a port number (in your server/IIS settings) - it's *your* API so you "dictate" how external "friends" can access/connect.

Caveats:

As mentioned above, just like in your local environment (which is less restrictive being local), in production/live internet, aside from the standard ports (80, 443, 20, 21, 22, 25, etc.) you may run into issues with firewalls, which ports to use (conflict with other existing services), etc. which is a broad topic  and frankly its been a long time since I've done net ops - TLDR; if they are completely separate applications (as it seems), then you're probably better off doing same on live - e.g. subdomains - `www.foo.com` (mvc) `api.foo.com` (api) and not deal with assigning port numbers *manually* at all (defaults will apply - `80` for `http`, `443` for `https`).

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate multiple origins with commas:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:2256,http://localhost:2266", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.cors.enablecorsattribute.enablecorsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute.):

> Parameters **origins** Type: System.String Comma-separated list of origins
>   that are allowed to access the resource. Use "*" to allow all.

Answer (score 0):

The ports which are using for your Web API application hosting will not be accessible outside of your computer and also it might get changed when you close and open Visual Studio and run Web API again.

It would be best to host your Web API using a domainname (such as "apionlocal.com") on local machine and create a host entry on the local machine.

The host entry would look like `127.0.0.1 apionlocal.com`

Retrieve netrowk IP of your computer by running "ipconfig" command on command prompt and share it with your friend.

Your friend also need to enter the host entry on his machine with the IP of your machine.

The host entry would look like `<<your computer IP>> apionlocal.com`

Your friend need to call API using the domainname "apionlocal.com".

You can configure multiple origins in "EnableCors" using comma separated values.

```
EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:2256,<<Url of your friend's application>>", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: Note: Assumptions you're making - `ipconfig` - Is the "friend" in same local (sub) net? If not, Is that the publicly route-able IP or not? If yes: Is the local machine running IIS that has been configured for external communications? If not: more stuff to do in addition to checking prior mentioned IIS check

Comment: Yes I making assumption that both the computers are in the same network. If that's not the case then surely there is more work to do.